# Install Brother MFC295CN drivers to Ubuntu

Tags: printing, dpkg, brother

I'm trying to get the drivers for my printer going, and not doing well. I tried the following: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1377270 and the `sudo dpkg -i PACKAGE.deb` format. It installs the printer, but then doesn't see the printer via USB. Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to follow the instructions [on this page](http://welcome.solutions.brother.com/bsc/public_s/id/linux/en/instruction_prn1a.html). I installed a Brother HL2250DN just one hour ago and it works perfectly.

Because the instructions are a bit hard to follow, here the summary for Ubuntu (with updated instructions for cups):

**(0. If you are a 64-Bit Ubuntu user:)**

`sudo apt-get install ia32-libs lib32stdc++`

**1. Turn on the printer**

**2. Download the LPR and cupswrapper driver** from [this page](http://welcome.solutions.brother.com/bsc/public_s/id/linux/en/download_prn.html#MFC-295CN) (you need the .deb packages).

**3. Open a terminal** by pressing `CTRL+ALT+T`.

**4. Install the LPR driver**

In the terminal type `dpkg  -i  --force-all  downloaded-lpr-driver` where "downloaded-lpr-driver" is the filename of the downloaded deb for the LPR driver (something like `mfc295cnlpr-1.1.3-1.i386.deb`)

**5. Install the cupswrapper driver**

In the terminal type `dpkg  -i  --force-all  downloaded-cups-driver` where "downloaded-cups-driver" is the filename of the downloaded deb for the cupswrapper driver (something like `mfc295cncupswrapper-1.1.3-1.i386.deb`)

**6. Test your installation**

`dpkg  -l  |  grep  Brother`
should show both drivers to be installed.

**7. Setup cups**

Point your Browser to `http://localhost:631/printers` and click on your printer. In the Administration dropdown choose `Modify Printer`. The next step wants you to choose the connection type.

If you're using USB to connect the printer, the connection should allready be set to something like `usb://Brother/(your printer's model name)`. If your Printer is not listed, go to `http://localhost:631/admin` and add your printer.

If you're using a network connection, choose from `Discovered Network Printers` or if your printer was not discovered, select "LPD/LPR Host or Printer" or "AppSocket/HP JetDirect" and insert `lpd://(Your printer's IP address)/binary_p1` with the correct IP of your printer.

See [these examples](http://welcome.solutions.brother.com/bsc/public_s/id/linux/en/instruction_prn1a.html#cwi_img2) for working configurations.

Comment: I went through the steps provided.  I did it both with the USB cable and the network cable.  The printers show in both the http://localhost:631/printers page and the system settings / printer page.  All indicates the printer is available and idle.  However, when I send something to the printer, it flashes in the job queue as processing, these disappears as if it printed.  However, there isn't any action from the physical printer.

Answer (score 0):

You can install the printer drivers easily with the [free utility that Brother provides](http://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadlist.aspx?&c=us&lang=en&prod=mfc295cn_all&os=128&type3=625&dlid=dlf006893_000). Retreive and run the file by opening up the terminal and running these commands (make sure you acknowledge and accept the license agreement, which can be found at the page I linked):

```
wget http://download.brother.com/welcome/dlf006893/linux-brprinter-installer-2.0.0-1.gz
tar xf linux-brprinter-installer-2.0.0-1.gz
rm linux-brprinter-installer-2.0.0-1.gz
chmod a+x ./linux-brprinter-installer-2.0.0-1
sudo ./linux-brprinter-installer-2.0.0-1
```

You will be walked through the installation. Once complete, you will have an item in your home folder named `linux-brprinter-installer-2.0.0-1`, which you can safely delete.