# Brother printer won't print but says it is receiving data?

Tags: printing, brother

I recently installed Ubuntu on my father's computer and also installed his new Brother printer. My first attempts with the printer I was able to install the drivers, but it wouldn't let me push the "print test page" button. I then went to this page
[Install Brother MFC295CN drivers to Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/211933/install-brother-mfc295cn-drivers-to-ubuntu)
and after following those instructions I was able to push the "print test page" button. The printer now says "receiving data" but then never prints the page. When I go to the printing queue it says that the job is completed. 
I am very new to Ubuntu and not a programmer or anything so I am out of ideas on how to fix this. Please help :)

Comment: @For those who approve edit "Brother -> Brother's". Brother is a printer vendor :-)

Answer (score 2):

I had a very similar problem with my Brother printer: it always said that the printer was "processing" the document, but my problem was that I was using IPP instead of AppSocket/JetDirect.

How is your printer connected to your computer? Is it connected via a Parallel port? Is it simply wired in through USB? Or are you and the printer both connected to a router?

My setup was: printer wired into router via Ethernet, computer connected to router's Wi-Fi.
Here's what I had to do:

[image]

I'll need more information on your setup to really help you a lot, but if your printer is set up like mine, that might be worth a shot.

NOTE: if that doesn't work for you, see if you have any luck with Brother's [official drivers](http://www.brother-usa.com/downloads/default.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with my Brother dcp7065dn all in one.

After trying several fixes, my solution was to follow the directions / RTFM.  I went to the Brother support site, downloaded the install script, and ran the install script.
http://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadhowto.aspx?c=us&lang=en&prod=dcp7065dn_all&os=128&dlid=dlf006893_000&flang=4&type3=625

In my defense, Ubuntu has wizard can install the printer in a way that looks legit, but doesn't actually print.

Comment: Same here with 19.10 and a different brother printer LOL just said "receiving data" then "incomplete".