# installing Brother DCP-J315W

Tags: 12.04, installation, drivers, printing, brother

I want to install a Brother DCP-J315W printer. I use Ubuntu 12.04 
When I search in Brother solutions center there are drivers but they come with the instruction too bad to install.
Are there other drivers? 
Should I use another version of Ubuntu?

Comment: Did you follow [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/211933/install-brother-mfc295cn-drivers-to-ubuntu) for your install?

Answer (score 1):

There is indeed a very easy solution:

- Install all brother drivers by terminal `sudo apt-get install "brother-*` or by synaptic
- Search for the printer name, e.g. `dpkg -S DCP`
- Install the nearest match, in your case DCP 310CN

Answer (score -1):

quote too much

This is not working. Should be as follows:

`apt-get install brother-*` in >Terminal.

Printer is now working

Comment: How is this different to the first step in the first answer to the question? Are you saying that the 2nd and 3rd steps are not necessary?